# I just accidentally replaced my whole php code with another file in cPanel - Is there any way I could get that code back?

Tags: php, cpanel

I was working on `response.php` file, and I wanted to open another file `sample.php` so I changed the path & clicked on reopen file :

[image]

As it was processing, I accidentally clicked the save code button again - since the file path now had `sample.php`, (the code still had response file's code in it - as the sample file's code was not loaded till now) it now saved the response file's code in sample file - and somehow it closed the tab itself! So now both the files - response.php and sample.php have the exact same code, and since the tab closed, I can't undo the change in the sample.php file ‍♀️

What should I do to get my sample.php's code back?

I hope you understand my problem..

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't have any problem if you had a copy of the files on your local computer before you uploaded them on your server. As far as I know, the sample.php is gone for good.

Comment: Yeah I admit my mistake  I think I deserved that. Thanks!